# JSF // Primefaces // Buttons not showing.. apple vs windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I have a mysteroius problem. My classmates and me are programming an project in eclipse with the components java faces, tomcat V9, mySQL, eclipse java EE. So everything was fine since we changed our views into primefaces and a css layout. My mates (working on an apple pc) can run the project without any problems. On our login-page they see the buttons for username + passwort. When I run the login.xhtml I see they css-layout with our logout button and welcome-header but I don't see the commandbuttons (username and password). I am working on a windows pc and have all the components installed that they have. Okay I have to include more JARS (javax.faces-2.2.8 , jstl-1.2, mysql-connector, primefaces-6.0) than they but in the past everything works the same .. 
In the markers view (eclipse) is no problem showing, in the console are many information tags and some warnings but it seems that there is also everything fine.
So how could I help you with information that you can fix my problem :p

This is my console output:

```
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Nov 3 2016 20:59:41 UTC
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            10.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\BLABLABLA\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\BLABLABLA\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\blablabla\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\blablabla\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\blablabla\Desktop\eclipse-jee-neon-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 847 ms
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMATION: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\BLABLABLA\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\A_K_Projekt.xml
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:A_K_Projekt' did not find a matching property.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:45 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:45 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMATION: Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) für Kontext '/A_K_Projekt' wird initialisiert.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:45 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMATION: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMATION: Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) für Kontext '/A_K_Projekt' wird initialisiert.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMATION: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager addBean

///And many Warnings of these///

WARNUNG: JSF1074: Verwalteter Bean mit dem Namen 'projektManagedBean' wurde bereits registriert.  Ersetzen des bestehenden Klassentyps des verwalteten Beans controller.ProjektManagedBean durch controller.ProjektManagedBean.
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager addBean

///And many Warnings of these///


org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMATION: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\blablabla\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\A_K_Projekt.xml has finished in 4,355 ms
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Mär 03, 2017 8:35:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 4754 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possibilities it is a bit overwhelming to help constructively.
There are three general areas that this problem could be coming from:
1) Mac vs. Windows 
2)  browsers differences (i.e.,. IE, safari, chrome, firefox)
3) application state/sessions

It is most likely the application state/sessions.

For a test can you delete any cookies in your browser related to the app then reload the page.

Comment: At first thanks for your advice. I deleted the cookies and switched the browser but it doesn't work :-/

Comment: Upps accidentally pressed enter.. sorry!
Can you please explain me your point 3) application state/sessions ?
On which things should I have to look ?